# Core Data save UIImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have a Core Data in this database should I save images, so how can do to save an image that is just takes URL ...
Example please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Large images (>100 kb) should not be saved in CoreData, as it would really increase your managed object's memory footprint.

For these images I would save the path in CoreData as a string or an URL and then load the image if you need it.

In principle you can save anything as an attribute in a CoreData entity if it can be archived into a `NSData` object. There are examples in the CoreData documentation of how to save a `UIColor` to the database which uses exactly this technique.

Check out the [CoreRecipes sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008913) in which an image is attached to each recipe. This is basically the same thing you want to do.

Comment: CoreRecipes Sample code does not save url/path of an image. It is taking thumbnailview of image and saving it. I referred to that sample code.