# saving image with Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift4

I'm trying to save a user profile picture with CoreData but don't understand how to proceed.

I know I have to create an entity and I read it have to be BinaryData type, but then I don't understand how to save it and load it.

I tried this way :

```
let profilePicture = UserPicture(context: AppDelegate.viewContext)
profilePicture.userProfilePicture = profilPictureImageView.image?.pngData()
    try? AppDelegate.viewContext.save()
```

But doesn't work.
I did't find anything clearly enough help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Core Data save UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913399/core-data-save-uiimage)

Comment: You shouldn't store _complete images_ in `Core Data` . _Instead_, you should save image in `Documents Directory` and save path for that image inside `Core Data`

Comment: @ShubhamBakshi You can add an image to Core Data and select the "use external files" option for the attribute in the Core Data entity; Core Data will then manage the reference to he BLOB for you, including deleting the file when the object is removed from Core Data.  This is simpler than managing the references yourself

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks, I was not aware of that . Thanks a lot mate !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For save image in CoreData you must convert the image into DATA type then you can save it into CoreData.This code may useful to save image in CoreData.

```
@IBOutlet weak var profileimg: UIImageView?

let data = (profileimg?.image)!.pngData()
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer.viewContext
let newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Entity", into: context!)
newUser.setValue(data, forKey: "img")

do {
    try Constant.context?.save()
}
```

Make sure the key you enter is correct. Must check box of the Allow External Storage in the Data model Inspector.But I not to recommended to save image in CoreData. Hope this would be helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can convert images to string and store them in the core data.

```
self.selectedImage?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)?.base64EncodedString()
```

and load images from core data with this code

```
 if let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: todo.img as! String, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) {
   let image = UIImage(data: decodedData)
   Image(uiImage: image!)}
```